# Angular material design using $mdToast, toast wont show on my website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Helo,
I am new to AngularJS, and I just started using $mdToast basic function Show(). Here is my complete code for this problem, hope you can help me.

```js
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngCookies',
    'ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ngAria', 'ngMessages',
    'myApp.view0',
    'myApp.view1',
    'myApp.view2',
    'myApp.version',
    'myApp.view3',
    'myApp.view4',
    'myApp.view5',
    'myApp.view6'
])
        .run(function ($rootScope, $cookies, $http) {
            $rootScope.loggedin = false;
            $rootScope.loggedinUser = {};

            var loginCredentials = $cookies.get('logincredentials');

            $http.get('https://localhost:8181/WebApplicationStom/webresources/domain.login', {headers: {
                    Authorization: loginCredentials
                }}).success(function (data) {
                if (data.ime == '123') {
                    $rootScope.loggedinUser = data;
                    $rootScope.loggedin = true;
                } else {
                    $rootScope.loggedin = false;
                    $rootScope.loggedinUser = {};
                }
            });






        })

        .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view0'});
            }])





        .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModal', '$log', '$rootScope', '$http', '$cookies', '$mdToast', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log, $rootScope, $http, $cookies, $mdToast) {
                $scope.animationsEnabled = true;
                $scope.username = '';
                $scope.password = '';
                $scope.dialogMessage;


                $scope.logout = function () {
                    $rootScope.loggedinUser = {};
                    $rootScope.loggedin = false;
                    $cookies.remove('logincredentials');



                }
                $scope.login = function () {

                    if ($scope.username != '' && $scope.password != '') {

                        $http.get('https://localhost:8181/WebApplicationStom/webresources/domain.login', {headers: {
                                Authorization: $scope.username + ':' + $scope.password
                            }}).success(function (data) {
                            if (data.ime == '123') {
                                $rootScope.loggedin = true;
                                $rootScope.loggedinUser = data;

                                $cookies.put('logincredentials', '1:1');
                            } else {
                                $rootScope.loggedin = false;
                                $rootScope.loggedinUser = {};
                                $scope.dialogMessage = 'Uneli ste pogresan username i/ili password';
                            }
                        });
                    } else {

                        $scope.dialogMessage = 'Unesite username i password';
                    }


                }



                $scope.open = function (size) {

                    $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                        size: size,
                        resolve: {
                            items: function () {
                                return $scope.items;
                            }
                        }
                    });


                };


                $scope.openToast = function () {
                    $mdToast.show('Hello!');
                };
            }])

        .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items, $rootScope) {

            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> 
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Stomatoloska ordinacija</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css"> 
        <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.min.css">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
              rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>

        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.css">

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-cookies.js"></script>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>



        <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.min.js"></script>


        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    </head>
    <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/view0">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#/view1">Mesto</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/view2">Lekar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/view3">Pacijent</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/view4">Usluga</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/view5">Poseta</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/view6">view6</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                            <li><a href="#" ng-click="open()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login/Logout</a></li>
                            <li><a ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{loggedinUser.user}}</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>


        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <div class="page">

          
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Primary</md-button>


    <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl" >
        <md-button ng-click="openToast()">
            Open a Toast!
        </md-button>       
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

            <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
            <div class="container">    

            <div id="loginbox" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3"> 

            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  ng-click="cancel()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

            <div class="panel panel-default" >
            <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title text-center">Login/Logout</div>
            </div>     

            <div class="panel-body" >

            <form name="form" id="form" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

            <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input id="user" type="text" class="form-control" name="user" value="" placeholder="User" ng-model="username">                                        
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"  ng-model="password">
            </div>                                                                  

            <div class="form-group">
            <!-- Button -->
            <div>
            <h4>{{dialogMessage}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="cancel();logout();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> Logout</button>   
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="cancel();login()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> Login</button>   




            </div>
            </div>

            </form>     

            </div>                     
            </div>  
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </script>



    </div>
    <div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">



        <div id="footer">Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

    </div>
    <!-- In production use:
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
    -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js"></script>


    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <script src="view0/view0.js"></script>
    <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
    <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>
    <script src="view3/view3.js"></script>
    <script src="view4/view4.js"></script>
    <script src="view5/view5.js"></script>
    <script src="view6/view6.js"></script>

    <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
    <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
    <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

So the problem is not with the libraries included, i tried that and it didnt work. I should also mention that I am using angularJS seed as a child of project.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: can you make a fiddle or plunker ?

Comment: @Jigs Here you are http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojOvQR
this is very simple example that I was based on

Comment: Are you getting any $injector:modulerr errors? Or other errors?

Answer (score 0):

Toast require modules `ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'`. I think you should get rid of [assets-cache.js](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js) which is used by `ngmaterial` in default in `codepen` sample  . In [assets-cache.js](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js)  you have a "MyApp" module defined in it . and redefining this module again in your file gives error.Try avoiding file and add `ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'` module dependencies to your module . This should definitely solve your problem.

Here is a [sample codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xweKmm)

Comment: That didn't work either, I managed to to get rid of errors, but still cant see toast. Thanks anyway

Comment: Yes, 
assets-cache.js is used by default in example, I didnt use it, I wrote down 4 libraries relative to this question that i was using.

Comment: I know,
I also provided working example of code pen but when i apply it in my project it's not working properly

Answer (score 0):

Just click on "Settings" button on codepen, go to javascript tab and make sure you've got all of these dependencies included in your html.

Error tells you don't have it imported properly.

Comment: I did that first, Than i deleted assets-cache.js as @Jigs told me, but neither of these solutions worked for me.

Comment: Could you share more code with us?

HTML (entire template, without unrelated content), js module and controller? Maybe there's a syntax mistake somewhere else.

Comment: Here it is, whole code related to this topic  @MateuszSip

Answer (score 0):

The toast is probaly displayed behind another element. Use parent to append your toast to an HTML element:

```
 $scope.showSimpleToast = function () {
            $mdToast.show($mdToast.simple().textContent('Hello!').parent("#HTMLelemID"));
        };
```

parent() appends toast to the root element of the application by default. 
Access $mdToast documentation [here](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.1/api/service/$mdToast)